# Meaning of なかなか顔の皮分厚い

Tags: meaning

> 「いずれにせよ……何とかしてこのハイスクールを、面白いモノにせねばならないな。このままだとストレスでスヴェータが爆発してしまうこともありうる」
>
> スヴェータ「はい、爆発しますね]
>
> 「**なかなか顔の皮分厚い**なお前」

Why does he say なかなか顔の皮分厚い and what does it mean?

As its not obvious from context, スヴェータ is a bomb.

Comment: She basically threatened him by saying that she is going to blow up

Comment: This is same to 厚顔無恥.

Answer (score 5):

It's based on the idiomatic expression 面{つら}の皮{かわ}が厚い{あつい} ("(one's) facial skin is thick"), meaning someone *has some nerve* or *is shameless*. In the quote 顔{かお}の皮{かわ}分厚い{ぶあつい}, 面{つら} is swapped for 顔{かお} (both mean the same thing: *face*), 厚い{あつい} becomes more emphatic 分厚い{ぶあつい}, and the subject marker が is dropped, as sometimes happens in casual conversation. なかなか is a moderate intensifier (like "quite" or "rather").

The person is probably referring to スヴェータ's readiness and bare-facedness in admitting that she will, indeed, explode.